# Ideas on how to animate the transition of the content with in the same view

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

[image]I have recently started to learn Xamarin.iOS and I am in the process of implementing a book application with multiple pages in it. I understand the navigation between the different view controllers. But I am wondering how to implement the transition the content within the same view but have the same view transition animation effect?

Any ideas on how I may want to approach in implementing this functionality in Xamarin.iOS?

Thanks in advance.

Update: When I click forward or rewind buttons, I would like to load a new background image and on the same view and have the animation as if we are moving to navigating to a different view.

Comment: Can you just post some screenshot or some similar effect, can't get your meaning clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
UIView.BeginAnimations(string.Empty, System.IntPtr.Zero);
UIView.SetAnimationDuration(0.3);
//Your Code
SetNeedsDisplay();
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```